# Check-in as a Foursquare Page?

Tags: foursquare

does anybody know how to check-in now as a Foursquare Page? It worked in the past.

I do usually check-in as a foursquare.com/airsmolik … and I'm using this plugin to show it on my website airsmolik.com/contact/

The plugin is working but the "Check-in" button on desktop version of Foursquare venues disappeared for pages.

Does anybody knows how to check-in as a page now?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There was possibility to check-in as a page if you know the venue URL exactly on website of 4SQ. But currently this option is completely missing.

I did not find some clue about this change in 4SQ help. Their support does not know, that it was even possible in history.

Also make new page is really hidden. History of check-ins as page is still shown in venue details. So I do not know, I mean it was disabled and is no longer possible.

**Update 2015-04-14:** I ask 4SQ support and answer is: "[Currently that is not an option!](https://twitter.com/4sqSupport/status/587642745998614528)"